# How to develop Table with user input where like excel sheet I can input values & it can calculate values?

Tags: powerbi

I have a table with

1. No. of CPUs
2. Size of Memory
3. Storage Size

The users will input the values to this table and the corresponding cost will be calculated.

I have done this in excel sheet with formulas. How I can do this in the PowerBI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power BI is not designed to allow free-form user input like Excel.

What you could possibly do is create some pre-populated tables with all of the options you have and allow the user to select them via dropdowns and then write a measure to calculate the cost.

Comment: Thanks for your response and it gives me insight of not moving in wrong direction. Still keep this question open if there is any other better hack to do this? I did this in Tableau but getting the alignment is not easy for me in Tableau so switched to PowerBI and exploring...